# File pointer only read the first entry

Tags: c++, struct, file-pointer

Good day everyone. My program is about a Computer Shop (Laptop). So, people can buy laptop through this program and "PCPurchase" is the function that gonna handle the customer transaction.

I use file-pointer and struct to save information about all the laptops. And of course, the struct store more than 1 type of laptops because obviously this is a laptop shop.

I encounter a problem where user can only buy (enter name) of the first entry (first laptop) in the struct. Here: `cout << "Enter the laptop company and name you want to buy: " << endl;`

If customer enter the name of 2nd laptop,3rd and so on, it will jump to line 
`cout << endl << "\tNot available!" << endl; cout << "\tPress A to try again or B to return to main menu" << endl;`
It indicates that the laptop's name is not in database which actually is.

Can I know what the problem here actually is?

```
int PCPurchase()
{
    struct customer cust;
    system("color 0A");
    char laptop[100];
    double total_bill;
    const double TAX=0.06;

    system("cls");
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
    cout << "\t\tCustomer Dashboard" << endl;
    cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;

    fptr=fopen("laptop.txt","ab+");
    cout << "Available laptops: " << endl;
    rewind(fptr);
    while(fread(&PC,sizeof(PC),1,fptr)==1)
    {
        cout << endl << "Laptop company and name: ";
        cout << PC.laptopcompany << endl;
        cout << "RAM: ";
        cout << PC.RAM << endl;
        cout << "Processor: ";
        cout << PC.Processor << endl;
        cout << "Price: RM";
        cout << PC.price << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue purchase" << endl;
    getch();
    fflush(stdin);

    getInfo(cust); //get information of customer

    cout << "Enter the laptop company and name you want to buy: " << endl;
    cout << "(Type 'RETURN' if you do not want to purchase)" << endl << endl;
    gets(laptop);
    rewind(fptr);
    while(fread(&PC,sizeof(PC),1,fptr)==1)
    {  
        if(strcmpi(PC.laptopcompany,laptop)==0)
        {
            cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
            cout << "\tYou have selected" << endl;
            cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
            cout << "Laptop company and name: ";
            cout << PC.laptopcompany << endl;
            cout << "RAM: ";
            cout << PC.RAM << endl;
            cout << "Processor: ";
            cout << PC.Processor << endl;
            cout << "Price: ";
            cout << PC.price << endl;

            total_bill=PC.price+(PC.price*TAX);

            cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision (2);
            cout << "Name: "<< cust.name << endl; // struct output
            cout << "Email: "<< cust.email << endl;
            cout << "Phone Number: " << cust.number << endl;
            cout << "Your total bill (including 6% tax): RM" << total_bill << endl;
            cout << setfill ('-') << setw (55) << "-" << endl;

            cout << endl << "\tPress 1 to return to main screen!";
            cout << endl << "\tPress 2 to quit the program!";

            char afterpurchase;
            afterpurchase=getche();

            if (afterpurchase=='1')
            {
                fclose(fptr);
                main();
            }
            else
                exit_system();
        }
        else if(strcmpi("RETURN",laptop)==0)
            main();
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "\tNot available!" << endl;
            cout << "\tPress A to try again or B to return to main menu" << endl;
            char choice1;
            choice1=getche();
            choice1=toupper(choice1); // Transform to uppercase

            switch (choice1)
            {
                case 'A': fclose(fptr);
                          PCPurchase();
                          break;

                default : fclose(fptr);
                          main();
                          break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that you forgot the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: the computer is doing exactly what you told the computer to do, and not what you want it to do. You told the computer: go back to the beginning of the file, read a record from the file, compare it to the entered name, and if it doesn't match, print "not available". Those are (some of) your instructions to your computer. Therefore, if you enter the name from the second record in the file, the computer does exactly what you told it to do. P.S. Calling `main()` like this is wrong. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Oh alright I got it thanks! BTW is there any other way to go to main without calling it?

Comment: Yes. You should know about using the `return` statement. Use it to return to the caller, and, if necessary, then return to its caller, all the way back to your `main()`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hey, I am so sorry to bother you again but I still cannot fix this problem even though I understood what you meant. How exactly is for the program to compare the entered name by the user with each of the records from the file? (in a loop..?) I thought it is already in a loop and compare with each of the records.

Comment: You are correct. It compares the name with each record, and if it doesn't match the name the code prints "Not available". It performs each comparison starting with the first record of the file, and if it doesn't match the entered name it prints "Not available". So, if the entered name doesn't match the first record of the file, it then prints this message. This is exactly what you told your computer to do. What exactly don't you understand? Start from the beginning of the file. Read a record. Compare. Doesn't match? Print "not available". Very simple.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually I understand. But the problem is if I enter the 2nd record or so on it prints not available although it actually exists in the file. It prints available **only** if I enter the **1st record** in the file. I do not have any idea which code is the cause of that.

Comment: Of course it prints "not available", because you start the comparison with the first record, it doesn't match the first record so it prints "not available". That's it. That's what the shown code does. The code ***does not*** compare the name with every record of the file, and only prints "not avaliable" if none of them match. That's not what you told your computer to do. I already explained what you told your computer to do, and that's not it. If you want your computer to only print the message if none of the records in the file match, then that's what you will need to tell your computer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik oh okay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of else statement. If you want to buy the laptop from the second record of the data and so on, it will compare with the first record and will not return true. So, it will proceed to else statement and will not repeat the while loop. Simply change the else statement to make the loop working.